# How can I customize a nested serialized list of django model objects to be key/value pairs instead?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

lets say I have models like so:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Lab,null=True, related_name='devices')

class Lab(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Where a lab can have multiple devices.
When I create serializers I am able to get something back like this:

```
{'name':'My Lab','devices':[{'name':'Device 1','model':'iPhone'},{'name':'Device 2','model':'iPad'}]}
```

However, what I would like to get back is key/value pairs instead of a list of devices, like so:

```
{'name':'My Lab','devices':{'Device 1':{'model':'iPhone'},'Device 2':{'model':'iPad'}}}
```

I'm imagining I have to use the `SerializerMethodField` to make this work, but I am having trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, sometimes just writing the question out helps my brain figure out the answer.

this is what I came up with:

```
class LabSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    devices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = Lab
        fields = ('name','devices')

    def get_devices(self, obj):
        devices = {}
        for d in Device.objects.filter(lab = obj):
            serializer = DeviceSerializer(d)
            devices[d.name] = serializer.data
        return devices
```

Comment: I imagine that that's the best way to go about it. I question the use-case, but if this is what you need, that's the way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks. As far as the use-case goes, I wan't to be able to pull info for any device from a lab in O(1) time.